# Error when updating Sharepoint List View

Tags: list, error, list-view

I have created a standard Contacts list on my sharepoint site, and then I want to customize it's default view. I go to the ViewEdit.aspx page, select or remove any columns to display and post the form. Then I'm redirected to the `mysharepointsite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001` page with response status 404. There are no logs according this case in ULS also.

Does anybody have any ideas? Thx in advance.

Comment: Does this happen when creating other views for other lists or just this particualar one?

Comment: Yes, creating other views also causes the same problem.

Comment: Are there any customizations in the environment, or is it pure OOTB?

Comment: There were no changes to the Contacts List Template, it's out of the box.

Comment: I just ran into this problem in SharePoint 2013... I was having trouble with some of my views on a table that I copied from SP2003 with Metalogix Content Matrix, so I re-created the views, but the re-directs didn't work when I hit OK after modifying the view. This list is a stock list with no customizations. Has anyone solved this?

Comment: even I have the same problem. Anyone out there??